# PHP check thrown exception type

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

Of course in PHP you can catch all thrown exceptions with:

```
try{
    /* code with exceptions */
}catch(Exception $e) {
    /* Handling exceptions */
}
```

But is there a way to check the exception type of the thrown exception from inside the catch block?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can use [`get_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php):

```
try {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Non Sequitur!", 1);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo get_class($e);
}
```

Answer (score 30):

You can have multiple `catch` blocks to catch different Exception types.
See below:

```
try {
    /* code with exceptions */
} catch (MyFirstCustomException $e) {
    // We know it is a MyFirstCustomException
} catch (MySecondCustomException $e) {
    // We know it is a MySecondCustomException
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // If it is neither of the above, we can catch all remaining exceptions.
}
```

You should know that once an Exception is caught by a `catch` statement, none of the following `catch` statements will be triggered, even if they match the Exception.

You can also use the `get_class` method to get the full class name of any object, including Exceptions.

Comment: This in my opinion is the correct answer. to test the class type means you probably know what class type you are looking for is and therefore can create the appropriate catch statements.

Answer (score 14):

I think using [instanceof](https://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php) is a better solution, since it gives you more information than just class name which you get from `get_class`.

```php
class db_exception extends Exception {}
class db_handled_exception extends db_exception {}
class db_message_exception extends db_exception {}

function exception_type($ex){
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Type: [' . get_class($ex) . "]\n";
    echo "Instance of db_message_exception? " . var_export($ex instanceof db_message_exception,true) . "\n";
    echo "Instance of db_handled_exception? " . var_export($ex instanceof db_handled_exception,true) . "\n";
    echo "Instance of db_exception?         " . var_export($ex instanceof db_exception,true) . "\n";
    echo "Instance of Exception?            " . var_export($ex instanceof Exception,true) . "\n";
    echo '</pre>';
}

exception_type(new db_handled_exception());
exception_type(new db_message_exception());
exception_type(new db_exception());
exception_type(new exception());
```

Which will result as following

```
Type: [db_handled_exception]
Instance of db_message_exception? false
Instance of db_handled_exception? true
Instance of db_exception?         true
Instance of Exception?            true

Type: [db_message_exception]
Instance of db_message_exception? true
Instance of db_handled_exception? false
Instance of db_exception?         true
Instance of Exception?            true

Type: [db_exception]
Instance of db_message_exception? false
Instance of db_handled_exception? false
Instance of db_exception?         true
Instance of Exception?            true

Type: [Exception]
Instance of db_message_exception? false
Instance of db_handled_exception? false
Instance of db_exception?         false
Instance of Exception?            true
```

There might be cases that you want to categorize exceptions and do common actions.

Considering above example, you might want to only show exceptions that are of type `db_message_exception` and `db_handled_exception`; in this case since both of them are inherited from db_exception, you can simply say something like:

```php
if ($ex instanceof db_exception){
   // show error message
}
```

You might also want to wrap your exceptions to avoid spilling too much information to client screen:

```php
if (!($ex instanceof db_exception)){
    throw new db_handled_exception('an unhandled exception occured', -1, $ex)   
}
```