# Set DateTime in model from a TimeType input

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm doing a symfony 4 project and I got a small problem

I have a model with few DateTime value that represent the schedules of a shop

I want to let the administator change it by himself so I did a form that able the change.

```
        $formBuilder->add($schedule->getDay().'_openAm', TimeType::class,
            array(
                'label' => $this->getDayWithNumber($schedule->getDay()),
                'input'  => 'datetime', 
                'widget' => 'choice', 
                'data' => $schedule->getSlotClosePM()
            )
        );
```

But when I want to set it in the model

```
  $schedule->setSlotOpenAM($form->get($scheduleDay."_openAm"));
```

The program crash...

So I tried to do that

```
   $schedule->setSlotOpenAM(new \DateTime($form->get($scheduleDay."_openAm")));
```

I also tried to print the value from the form but it always crash...

I surrounded my all of that with a try and catch (\Exception $e) where I print a small sentence and the $e->getMessage() but the getMessage and getTraceAsString crash too...

The $e->getCode return an empty string and the get_class or getClass crash when I try to understand which kind of exception is it [PHP check thrown exception type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316800/php-check-thrown-exception-type).

Can you tell me how should i convert my TimeType to a DateTime please or how can I get the data inside that kind of input ?

I searched in the documentations https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/time.html

But they just say how to add it in a form not how to use it when we get it back

Thank's !

Comment: You already specify the right format for your data by using the `input` option. Maybe the error lies somewhere else? What exactly is the error message and stack trace you get back?

Comment: I call the form with ajax, I don't see which error is it, I tried to surround the place where it crash with a try and catch but the Exception is not found :(

Comment: I also tried to use getType for watch if the form input change but it answer me object, so i guess that i get a good thing but Idk why I crashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was really easy finally :D !

```
    $schedule->setSlotOpenAM($form->get($scheduleDay."_openAm")->getData());
```

return a dateTime Value