# Laravel abort() not working inside try and catch

Tags: laravel

```
abort(403); <-- works fine, will display laravel abort page

try{
    $rows = DB::.......

    if ( !$Rows ) {
        abort(403);<-- this will become exception
    } else {

    }
} catch (Exception $e) {

}
```

I have a page when user request, if no rows I would like to use laravel abort(); to terminate the page.

however I have use try catch wrap my code, it will become catch an error and cause laravel abort() not working.

anyone how to fix this?

Comment: Don't catch the top level exception but the specific one that needs to be catched

Comment: i made a custom function to save log after I catch any error
thats why I wrap all my code inside it.

Comment: Find out which Exception is thrown by abort, check for the class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316800/php-check-thrown-exception-type and abort again in catch.... Or throw a self made exception and then abort in catch

Comment: What is it you're trying to catch from your query i.e. why does it need to be inside a `try/catch` in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

try this code

```
      try{
        abort(403);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        if($e->getStatusCode()==403)
            abort(403);
    }
```

Comment: Check this and let me know whether it was useful

Comment: thank you. how can I remember from where import these classes. my PHP storm when I press cntrl+space show me 1000 Exception reference Classes ;)

Comment: don't need add using for this type of Exception @sabertabatabaeeyazdi

Answer (score 2):

`\Exception` is the base class of all php exceptions. So when you are catching `\Exception` in try.. catch block, you are practically catching all exceptions.

when you do abort(403), laravel internally throws `HttpException` with statusCode 403.

If you see in laravel, `HttpException` extends php's [`\RuntimeException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.runtimeexception.php) which indeed at the end extends [`\Exception`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) class.

The solution would be to catch a specific exception instead of catching `\Exception`. For example, if you are worried about mysql connection, you can catch `PDOException`. It's always better to be specific about exceptions you are catching.

```
<?php 

try{
    $rows = DB::someaction()...;

    if (!$rows) {
        abort(403);
    }
    // Do stuff with $rows

}catch (PDOException $e) {
    // take action for specific exception
}
```